# Can't get :active or :hover effects to work in Android

Tags: android, css, mobile, hover

In the Android default browser, I can't get `:active` or `:hover` to work at all. I know `:hover` and `:active` aren't recommended for use on mobile, but considering they work consistently everywhere except the default Android browser, I figured I'd try it. This code works fine on iOS and Windows Phone, but not on Android, and I can't figure out why.

CSS:

```
* {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}

#clickBox {
    background: #CCC;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100px;
}

#hiddenBox {
    background: #BBB;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    transition: height 0.5s;
    width: 120px;
}

#clickBox:active ~ #hiddenBox, #clickBox ~ #hiddenBox:active, #clickBox:hover ~ #hiddenBox, #clickBox ~ #hiddenBox:hover {
    height: 50px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<section id="clickBox" aria-haspopup="true">
    Click here!
</section>
<section id="hiddenBox">
    This appears!
</section>
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gDRK2/1/

Comment: What's the point of a hover state when on a mobile platform you usually click or swipe?

Comment: To pull up a menu, without JavaScript. I'm a fan of pure CSS solutions, and I've been working on this menu for quite a while. It's so close to perfect, it's extremely frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. For some reason, Android was firing the `:hover` event only when the user rotated the phone. I have no idea why that would be, but it is.

So, this is how I fixed it:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("android") > -1) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("nav").children("a").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).next("ul").css("transform","rotate(90deg)");
            $(this).next("ul").css("transform","rotate(0deg)");
        });
    });
};
```

Basically, I rotate the thing I want to appear on hover, then immediately rotate it back. It causes the `:hover` to work as expected. It makes literally no sense to me, but it works.

If anyone has any questions about implementing this, please let me know.